# Embedded font doesn't recognize bold

Tags: xaml, silverlight, fonts

How can i reference a embbed font in my silverlight project, considering that there are multiple files for the same font?

I used the following tags in a Fonts.xaml file:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFamily">../../Resources/Fonts/segoeui.ttf#Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```

In another file I have a tag to link this fontfamily to any TextBlock.

When I have a simple TextBlock it works fine:

```
<TextBlock Text="Simple" />
```

But when i want a bold text, it is not working;

```
<TextBlock Text="Simple" Font-Weight="Bold" />
```

I Know that the bold font is in another file (segoeuib.ttf), but since I refer to a specific file, and not the font name, its not finding. How can i refer to both file, without having to add FontFamily tag to all my TextBlock that needs to display Bold text?

PS: If I use the Font family name, without the file name, it will work, but if my user doesn't have the font in his/her computer it wont work.

Comment: Is it assumed your "Font-Weight" property is just typo since it should be `FontWeight`? Oh, and might add I'm pretty sure SegoeUI is standard in SL and you can just hit it directly via <FontFamily x:Key="MyFamily">Segoe UI</FontFamily> without external reference.

Comment: It's not available on MAC.

Comment: This font was not available on MAC, so when i open my app in a mac machine, it was using another font, and messing all my interface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered how to do it, sharing in case someone has the same problems.

Instead of referring to the .ttf file, just put all font files in a zip and refer to the zip:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="MyFamily">../../Resources/Fonts/SegoeUI.zip#Segoe UI</FontFamily>
```